# How do I change the image in ImageView more than once?

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

My application adds a photo from your gallery to an ImageView just fine, but if I try and change the image (after one has already been selected) my app force closes. Is there a way to achieve this?

here is my code..

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

private String selectedImagePath;
private ImageView img;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimageview);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.taptoadd))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                }
            });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
   }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
   String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);


}
```

}

Comment: Its better if you post the code and stacktrace. Keep this in mind whenever you ask question on SO.

Comment: ok thanks! I will do that from now on.

Comment: you have written img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri); ..you need to use selectedImagePath over there..or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the image through code .

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

Comment: I want the user to be able to select a different photo if they do not like the photo they chose first.

Comment: u need to keep a counter for selecting picture and increment it accordingly. In ur code u have used SELECT_PICTURE but not managed it further.Also save the images with common name and a counter number like Image1, Image2, Image3 and so on..